# Meaning of "#define GOT_HERE() ((void)(__LINE__))"?

Tags: c, macros

I found this in a .c file while working with an open source library.

```
#define GOT_HERE() ((void)(__LINE__))
```

What does it mean? In the rest of the .c file, the macro is used like this:

```
GOT_HERE();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a macro that expands expands to `__LINE__` which in turn expands to the line number where the statement `GOT_HERE();`  was placed in the code.

`__LINE__` is a [predefined macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), of which there is quite a few.
This can be useful for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

it will give you the line number, from where it is called...it can be defined for diagnostic purpose...depends on your implementation